# Scala optional parameter of a Case class

Tags: scala

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val p = each_rsvp.extract[RSVPData]
p.venue.getOrElse(default = None)
```

I have done the extraction using case classes. RSVPData is a case class defined as follows:

```
case class RSVPData(
                     venue: Option[VenueDetails] = None,
                     visibility: String,
                     response: String,
                     guests: Int,
                     member: MemberDetails,
                     rsvp_id: Long,
                     mtime: Long,
                     event: EventDetails,
                     group: GroupDetails
                   )
```

As shown above, parameter 'venue' is an optional field of type VenueDetails which is also a case class.

```
case class VenueDetails(venue_name: String, lon: Double, lat: Double, venue_id: Int)
```

When I do:

```
p.venue.getOrElse(Default=None)
```

I get the output as :

```
VenueDetails(Waller Creek Pub House,-97.73584,30.266438,24179503)
```

The above is returned as 'Product with Serializable'. How to extract data from VenueDetails case class separately as venue name, latitude, longitude, venue id, from this output .

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that `p` is an `RSVPData` item. Correct? (

When you use `.getOrElse` on an `Option`, you are attempting to provide a default value in the case where no value is defined (that is, when the value is `None`). In other words, `getOrElse` gives you an opportunity to provide default venue details when none are available, so that you can handle both cases in a consistent manner. In your case, this argument should be an instance of `VenueDetails`.

By passing `None` as the argument to `getOrElse` you're saying that you want `None` if the `Option`'s value is `None` - which makes very little sense. Even worse, `getOrElse` now returns two types of value: a `VenueDetails` or `None`. So *Scala* determines the return type as those traits that are common to both of these types, which it has determined to be `Product with Serializable`. As a result, you can't treat the return value as a `VenueDetails`, and so you cannot access its members.

General *rule of thumb*: **NEVER pass `None` to `Option.getOrElse`**! ;-)

(As an aside, specifying the argument name in the call is unnecessary; `p.venue.getOrElse(None)` is simpler and equivalent to `p.venue.getOrElse(default = None)`.)

So, now it depends upon what you're trying to do, which isn't clear from your question. I'll try to provide a few examples...

This first example is more imperative than functional. It attempts to print out details of the venue:

```
// Is the venue defined? (If None, then it's undefined.)
if (p.venue.isDefined) {

  // Retrieve the defined details. Note that get throws an exception if p.venue is None.
  // BTW, detail's type is inferred to be VenueDetails.
  val details = p.venue.get
  println(s"Venue: ${details.venue_name}, loc: (${details.lon}, ${details.lat}), id: ${details.venue_id}")
}

// Handle the case where the venue details are undefined.
else {
  println("Venue details are unknown")
}
```

Here's a slightly more functional version:

```
val desc = p.venue.fold {

  // This argument is evaluated only if p.venue is None.
  "Venue details are unknown"
} {

  // This argument is executed only if p.venue is defined (not None).
  // Again, details is inferred to have type VenueDetails
  details =>
    s"Venue: ${details.venue_name}, loc: (${details.lon}, ${details.lat}), id: ${details.venue_id}"
}
println(desc)
```

This version uses a default VenueDetails instance for cases where the venue details are unknown:

```
// Default details for case where p.venue is None.
val defaultDetails = VenueDetails("Unknown", 0.0, 0.0, -1)

// Here, details will have type VenueDetails.
val details = p.venue.getOrElse(defaultDetails)
val desc = s"Venue: ${details.venue_name}, loc: (${details.lon}, ${details.lat}), id: ${details.venue_id}"
println(desc)
```

In this latter case, if p.venue is None, then the following will be printed:

```
Venue: Unknown, loc: (0.0, 0.0), id: -1
```

However, if p.venue is defined as per your example, then the following will be printed:

```
Venue: Waller Creek Pub House, loc: (-97.73584, 30.266438), id: 24179503
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this would work:

```
p.venue.map(_.venue_name).getOrElse(None)
```